# Displaying a flash message and redirecting to another page after Token mismatch exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a simple voting application where I try to prevent double submission using the back button by using csrf tokens. My route looks like this

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){
   Route::post('votesuccess', array('as' => 'votesuccess', 'uses'=>'VoteController@votesuccess'));
});
```

I have filters that looks like this

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
 {

  if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {

     return Response::to('voteresults');

      Session::flash('message', 'You are trying to vote twice!');

    }
});

Route::filter('no-cache',function($route, $request, $response){

  header("Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

});
```

Part of my controller looks like this

```
Session::put('_token', md5(microtime())); 

        // redirect
Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Cast your vote!');
return Redirect::route('voteresults');
```

It works fine and sure enough if someone clicks the back button and tries to re submit it brings `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException` which is all well and good except I want it to redirect to the `voteresults` view and display a flash message informing the user that they are trying to cheat. Any ideas about how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a handler for the `TokenMismatchException` a good place to put this would be in `start/global.php` and would look something like

```
App::error(function(TokenMismatchException $exception)
{
    Session::flash('message', 'You are trying to vote twice!');
    return Redirect::to('voteresults');
});
```

For more information on handling exceptions in Laravel have a look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors)

Comment: It works but it doesn't redirect to the `votesresults` view. It displays a blank page and instead goes to `votesuccess` view which is the controller for storing votes and redirecting to `votesresults`.The form for submitting the votes looks like this `{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'votesuccess/')) }}`. Any ideas?